# Do we want a Drupal Answers blog?

Tags: discussion

I just stumbled across this...all StackExchange communities are now able to run their own community blog, an effort dubbed [Blog Overflow](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).

Just throwing this out there...do we want one? Would there be anyone interested in maintaining/contributing to such a blog?

**EDIT**

Ideas for weening them off of Wordpress and on to Drupal are also welcome ;)

Comment: I am willing to help maintaining it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the blog system SE uses is WordPress. Shun the nonbelievers! [Shuuuuuuuuuun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5im0Ssyyus#t=1m17s)!

Comment: @MarkTrapp Ewww does it? Disregard the question then ;)

Comment: if they would allow a Drupal blog would you guys build it/maintain it?